# Prevent UIView's from being re-added to a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have refactored my code to use the latest iOS 5 methods of UITableViewCell reuse. However, subviews of the UITableViewCells being dequeued in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method are being re-added to the same cell's contentView or another cells.

How can I prevent the cell's subviews jumping to other cells and adding itself as a subview?

Thanks in advanced.

Edit---

I updated my code to check to see if the subviews are nil before adding them again as a subview, and it works perfectly, but only three images are ever displayed in each image view (avatarImageView and snapImageView). This is because the if statements only ever go through three times. Please can you tell me why this is occurring?

My console looks like this:

```
2012-01-06 03:25:39.497 App[1347:707] in snap
2012-01-06 03:25:39.500 App[1347:707] in avatar
2012-01-06 03:25:39.518 App[1347:707] in snap
2012-01-06 03:25:39.520 App[1347:707] in avatar
2012-01-06 03:25:42.593 App[1347:707] in snap
2012-01-06 03:25:42.595 App[1347:707] in avatar
```

Updated Code:

```
- (void) setPost:(TBPost *) _post {

    if (post != _post) {
        [post release];
        post = [_post retain];
    }

    ...

    if (self.snap == nil) {

        NSLog(@"in snap");

        NSString *str = [[_post snaps] objectForKey:TBImageOriginalURL];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
        [TBImageDownloader downloadImageAtURL:url completion:^(UIImage *image) {
            [self setSnap:image];
        }];

    }

    if ([self viewWithTag:-25] == nil) {
        UIImageView *pinView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"]];
        NSArray *r = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-5", @"-4", @"-3", @"-2", @"-1", @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
        int place = self.frame.origin.x + (self.frame.size.width / 2) - (pinView.frame.size.width / 2) + [[r objectAtIndex:rand() % [r count]] intValue];
        CGRect frame = [pinView frame];
        frame.origin.x = place;
        frame.origin.y = -5;
        [pinView setFrame:frame];
        [pinView setTag:-25];
        [self addSubview:pinView];
        [pinView release];
    }

    if (self.authorAvatar == nil) {

        NSLog(@"in avatar");

        NSURL *urls = [[[_post user] avatars] objectForKey:[[TBForrstr sharedForrstr] stringForPhotoSize:TBPhotoSizeSmall]];

        [TBImageDownloader downloadImageAtURL:urls completion:^(UIImage *image) {
            [self setAuthorAvatar:image];
        }];

        [self.authorAvatarImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [self.authorAvatarImageView.layer setCornerRadius:10];

    }

    if ([self viewWithTag:-26] == nil) {
        UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar_overlay"]];
        [iv setFrame:[self.authorAvatarImageView frame]];
        [iv.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [iv.layer setCornerRadius:6^7];
        [iv setTag:-26];
        [self addSubview:iv];
        [iv release];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but is sounds like your `UITableViewCell` subclass (assuming that's what you've posted) should implement a proper `-prepareForReuse` method which cleans up the cell.

Comment: Thanks, it is definitely to do with the prepareForReuse method, but I am unsure what to put in there in order to clean up the cell. Everything in the cell, variable-wise, is changed apart from the two UIImageViews, `snapImageView` and `authorAvatarImageView`, any ideas why?

Comment: could you post your `-prepareForReuse` code then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are using `addSubView` in your `tableView:cellForIndexPath:` method.

Using storyboard, you should create your custom cell in storyboard, meaning add whatever you want (e.g. label, button, etc.) / design them in IB (storyboard) and assign them **tags**!

In `tableView:cellForIndexPath:` method, reference to them

> ```
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>
> {
>  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeue....:@"cellID"];
>  UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
>  label.text = @"....";
>
>  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1002];
>  // etc.
>
>  return cell;
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Are the subviews being re-added by you?  If not, what you're seeing is just the same cell being reused.  Instead of removing and then re-adding the subviews, just update the subviews contents.